# AS3 socket cannot load data from

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, flash

I have searched internet for a lot of times but could not find any clue. I am using sockets to connect to socket server. (Also we tryed different socket policy files, but none worked)

```
    private var SERVER_URL : String = "http://192.168.0.105";
    private var PORT_NUMBER : int = 1435;

    private var _socket : Socket;

    // signal
    private var _signal : Signal;

    public function BackendService()
    {
        // nastavenie socketu
        _socket = new Socket();
        _socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
        _socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
        _socket.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
        _socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        _socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, HandleMsgFromServer); // ak pride sprava zo serveru

        Security.allowDomain("*");
        Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://192.168.0.105:8000/crossdomain.xml"); 

        // signal na dispatchovanie eventov
        _signal = new Signal();

        connect(); // I am doing it from other class, but for sake of example, I am calling from here
    }

    public function connect():void
    {
        _socket.connect(SERVER_URL, PORT_NUMBER);
    }
```

My crossdomain - socket policy file are sitting on port 8000 and looks like this:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I am getting this error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation:
>   file:///C:/projects/TennisHeroes/bin/TennisHeroes.swf cannot load data
>   from http://192.168.0.105:1435.

Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: You might want to enable `PolicyFileLog` in your `mm.cfg` to determine if the policy file is being loaded... also your policy file is missing the `?xml` header

Comment: I enabled policy file log in my mm.cfg
PolicyFileLog=1
PolicyFileLogAppend=1
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1

but not output msgs about policy file

Comment: For policy file... instead of involving a port number in the url, cant it just be loaded via `http://192.168.0.105/crossdomain.xml`? Once loaded & `Security` approved then you can try the `_sockets.connect` part. Just a thought...

Comment: PS: Also make sure the xml exists on that server so if you put same thing in browser `http://192.168.0.105/crossdomain.xml` it should show text of XML file. Also test by running the SWF from your server online instead from hard drive or IDE (could be your Flash settings preventing the SWF from accessing external data from online... because bad people also use this trick so its not allowed)

Comment: Tested everything but it did not work. Looks like server adress can not be with HTTP in "http://192.168.0.105" and only should use "192.168.0.105"